# unable to deploy struts2 war on tomcat7

Tags: deployment, struts2, tomcat7

I feel really stupid right now but I've been struggling all day long and I don't have a clue, some help would be kindly appreciated :)

I've developped a struts2 webapp which works fine when I run it through eclipse (indigo sr2) related to my servelt server apache tomcat 7.0.27 installed on my own computer. All I do is : right click on the folder of my webapp --> run as --> run on server. Then it runs nicely either in eclipse browser, or in other browser (chrome, firefox) when I copy and path the url adress of my servlets.

Now all I'd like to do is make it run without eclipse. So I exported my webapp in a .war file (right click on the webapp folder --> export --> War file), and tried to deploy it using the app manager tomcat web interface : all it asked me to do was to browse for the war file through my computer and to click on the deploy button. Easy going so far !

Then my webapp appears in the applications tab of the app manager interface, but when I click on the "run" button, all I get is this message :

> Failure : application for the context path /MMSProject could not start

(the original message is in French, I did not find how to change tomcat7 language, so this might not be the exact message you'd have in english, I hope this translation is close enough. *MMSProject* is the name of my webapp).

Therefore, I downloaded some struts2 webapp examples on the struts2 website and tried to deploy struts2-blank on tomcat7 using the same process. This one works perfectly fine : I can run it from tomcat app manager. So I guess my problem comes from my own war file and not from tomcat itself, but since it's generated by eclipse it seems weird to me that this part of the process could go wrong.

And so I'm stuck with that. Would you guys know :

- How can I get more information about what's going wrong (I looked in tomcat logs but did not find any error message). This could help me a lot to solve the problem !
- Any reason for what my webapp would run from eclipse but not directly from tomcat ?
- How can I make it run from tomcat ? :)

Thank you very much in advance for any help ! I'm kind of desperate right now, did not think deployment would be such a pain !

EDIT : 
I've double checked tomcat's log and actually found this in catalina.[date].log:

> - Grave: Error filterStart
>     juin 21, 2012 1:48:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
> - Severe: Context [/MMSproject] startup failed due to previous errors
> - juin 21, 2012 1:48:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
> - Grave: The web application [/MMSproject] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@2de3bcb5]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@427a269c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
> - juin 21, 2012 1:48:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
> - Grave: The web application [/MMSproject] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@617ceddc]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@50e43884]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

and this in localhost.[date].localhost :

> juin 21, 2012 1:48:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
>   SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager$FileRevision.needsReloading(FileManager.java:209)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.fileNeedsReloading(FileManager.java:60)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:325)
>       at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:168)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.conditionalReload(ConfigurationManager.java:220)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:61)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:774)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1247)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:747)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:222)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: there's no base error, you should simply try CLEAN and build again.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I found the anwser and wanted to post it in order to help someone who would have te same issue !

It's a tiny detail but it may save you a lot of struggling and praying time once you know it: before deploying don't forget to switch the struts devMode to false (in struts.xml file) if you had decided to use it at the begining of you development (ie : maybe some few hard coding weeks ago !).

So basically this is what you wanna have in struts.xml :

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```

instead of :

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

Good luck everybody !

Comment: Unless you want to work in devMode . . . that shouldn't prevent the app from running in tomcat7.

Comment: Well, although I indead don't really understand why it would have prevent the app from running in tomcat7, this is the only thing I changed and it suddenly worked... I'll set devMode back to true, see what happen and post a new comment to confirm or infirm this assumption. Maybe the devMode generated things related to my app that tomcat "did not like", in that case the answer would be in the logs I published...

Comment: that has nothing to do with app running.